# I am using sqlite on android when i insert text into integer columns i dont receive any errors and the foreign-key constraint doesn't work

Tags: android, sqlite

Here is the code below: I am creating 2 tables namely: Teacher and Credentials. I want the Credentials_ID column to reference the Teacher_ID column. Also the data-type constraint to  be obeyed. ie. I should not be able to insert an **integer** into **text** column and vice-versa.

Help please it's been two days already, I'm fed-up:

```
public class WinnersTeachersDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "winnersteachersbanana.db";

public WinnersTeachersDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
// Create a table to hold teachers details.
    final String SQL_CREATE_TEACHERS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Teachers.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
            Teachers._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +

            Teachers.COLUMN_FULL_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Teachers.COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +

            " UNIQUE (" + Teachers.COLUMN_MOBILE_NUMBER + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

    // Create a table to hold credentials details.
    final String SQL_CREATE_CREDENTIALS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Credentials.TABLE_NAME + " (" +

            Credentials._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            Credentials.COLUMN_TEACHER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            Credentials.COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            Credentials.COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +

            // Set up the teacherId column as a foreign key to teachers table.
            " FOREIGN KEY (" + Credentials.COLUMN_TEACHER_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
            Teachers.TABLE_NAME + " (" + Teachers._ID + "), " +

            " UNIQUE (" + Credentials.COLUMN_TEACHER_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";

sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TEACHERS_TABLE);
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CREDENTIALS_TABLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html); you'd have to enforce column types with a separate constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE ... (
    ...,
    FullName TEXT NOT NULL  CHECK(typeof(FullName) = 'text'),
    ...
);
```